# Teamcity Unmet Requirements: powershell_x86_Edition equals Desktop

Tags: powershell, teamcity, requirements

I just updated my TeamCity server and I am suddenly getting this error message on my build agent.

I made a copy of the old installation, and the buildAgent.properties are the exact same. The Plugin folder for powershell exists aswell.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Where is the error message ? and how are you updating your TC Server?

Comment: From which version to which version (most probably 2017.1.x) did you upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when moved the build agent from windows to linux, and found the solution [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/PowerShell#PowerShell-Cross-PlatformPowerShell).

In short:

1. Make sure powershell is installed on the server where the build agent is running.
2. You can set `Platform` and (Since TeamCity 2017.1) `Edition` properties at the PowerShell build step Edit page.

   - `Edition`: on windows `Desktop`, on linux `Core`
   - `Platform`: could be `x64` or `x86` based on installed version

If you set these properties correctly, it should meet the requirements, and you can use the build agent as before.